# Why is a generic type that extends an interface not assignable to a matching object?

Tags: typescript

I am getting this error

```
[ts] Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'A'.
```

with the below code

```
interface Action {
    type: string;
}

function requestEntities<A extends Action>(type: string) {
    return function (): A {
        return { type };
    };
}
```

Why isn't it assignable? `A` extends `Action`, which has only one property: `type`, which is a string. What's the problem here?

Is the problem that `A` could have more properties? then how do I tell TypeScript that `A` still only has the `type: string` property and nothing else?

**EDIT**

FYI the reason that I want to add the generic `A` is because `A` will have a *specific* string as the type property, e.g. `{ string: 'FETCH_ITEMS' }`.

Answer (score 5):

The generic isn't helping you here.  As you note, `A` can have more properties:

```
interface SillyAction extends Action {
   sillinessFactor: number;
}
requestEntities<SillyAction>('silliness');
```

There generally isn't a way in TypeScript to say that an object has *only* some set of properties, because TypeScript currently lacks [exact types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).

But in your case, you want the returned `Action` to have a `type` with a *specific* `string`; something like:

```
interface SpecificAction<T extends string> extends Action {
   type: T;
}
function requestEntities<T extends string>(type: T) {
    return function (): SpecificAction<T> {
        return { type };
    };
}
requestEntities('silliness'); // returns a function returning {type: 'silliness'}
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

> FYI the reason that I want to add the generic `A` is because `A` will have a specific string as the type property, e.g. `{ string: 'FETCH_ITEMS' }`.

Because you are sure that `A` is compatible with `Action`, you can reassure the compiler:

```
return { type } as A;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look what you can do on order to achieve stronger type safety 
(I didn't fully understand your task, but the approach should be clear from this example)

```
interface Action {
    type: string;
    amount: number;
}

const action: Action = { type: 'type1', amount: 123 }

function requestEntities<KEY extends keyof Action>(type: KEY) {
    return action[type]
}

requestEntities('type')
requestEntities('amount')

requestEntities('random-stuff')
```

[image: Shows error:]